# node.js Implementing http server - creating res req - browser stucks after first loading

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express

I want to share with you the way I designed my own http server to see if I may have issues I don't notice.
First, I'm using my http module with express server.
My server is currently "working". but.  I'm able to load a page. But When I'm trying to do refresh (after the first page load), it looks like there are pending requests and the browser stucks in loading.

I'm doing the following:

1. parsing the data till I have \r\n\r\n, cutting the data so I'm making a request object from the first part(before \r\n\r\n), and keeping the second part (after \r\n\r\n), because the client may send a request immediately one after another.
2. Every time I finish creating the request object, I'm calling the server's handler, and supply it my created request object + new response object (which I created also).

My questions are:

1. Is it a good design?
2. In my approach above, If I'm getting to requests one after another, I'll make two calls for the server handler with two new requests and two new responses. how do I make sure that every response won't interrupt with the other one? (They're writing to the same socket). Or the express server should take care of it?

That's my module:

```
var net = require('net');
var incomingMessage=require('./IncomingMessage');
var server;


var util = require('util');


var miniHttp;
miniHttp = {

STATUS_CODES: {
    404: 'Not Found',
    200: 'OK',
    204: 'No Content',
    205: 'Method Not Allowed',
    500: 'Internal Server Error'
},
Server: require('events').EventEmitter,


createServer: function (handler) {
    console.log('Server Started');
    var Server = require('events').EventEmitter;

    server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
        console.log('\n');
        console.log('*****************');
        console.log('SERVER: got a connection');
        /**
         *   Checking if timout or fallback timeout was set, if it wasn't defines the defaults (2 minutes).
         */
        if(server.timeout==null){
             console.log('server.timeout is null');
            server.timeout=120000;

            if(server.timeoutCallBack==null){
                server.timeoutCallBack=function(){console.log('about to destroy the function because of 2 min timeout');socket.destroy();};
            }
        }

        //Sets the timeout for every socket.
        socket.setTimeout(server.timeout,server.timeoutCallBack);

        var self = this;
        var IncomingMessage = require('./IncomingMessage');
        var ServerResponse = require('./ServerResponse');
        var req = '';
        var res;
        var socketData = {rawRequest: '', bodyLengthSent: 0};
        socket.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log('SOCKET: Received new data');
            console.log('SOCKET: data is ' + data);

            //For every new chunk of data, checks if there is a pending request which its body wasn't sent.
            if (req.method == "POST" && !req.isBodySent) {
                console.log('should send body');
                sendBody(socketData, data, req);
            }

            else{
                //Parsing the request by calling parseRequest function, very time there is enough data for a request
                //, Creating new request, when new request is ready, a request event is emitted
                parseRequest(socket, data, function (finalizedRequest) {
                    res = new ServerResponse(socket);
                    req = finalizedRequest;
                    self.emit('request', socketData,req, res,sendBody);
                });
            }


        });
        //timeout on the socket causes the server to emit a timeout
        socket.on('timeout',function(){self.emit('timeout',socket);});
        //error on the socket causes the server to emit an error
        socket.on("error",function(){self.emit('clientError',socket);});


        //Message parser,
        var rawRequestToSend = '';
        var endOfHttpMessageRegexp = /\r\n\r\n/g;
        var isContainsEndOfMessage;
        function parseRequest(socket, data, callBackFunction) {
            //First, adding the new data to the data that was already collected
            socketData.rawRequest += data;
            isContainsEndOfMessage = endOfHttpMessageRegexp.exec(socketData.rawRequest);
            //Checking if now, after the new data, there is a sign of end of message: \r\n\r\n
            if (isContainsEndOfMessage) {
                //if contains end of message , taking the first part till the \r\n\r\n and creating with it a new
                //request. the second part is kept
                rawRequestToSend = socketData.rawRequest.substring(0, socketData.rawRequest.indexOf('\r\n\r\n'));
                socketData.rawRequest = socketData.rawRequest.substring(socketData.rawRequest.indexOf('\r\n\r\n') + 4, socketData.rawRequest.length);
                console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
                console.log('rawRequest left is: '+socketData.rawRequest+'######');
                console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
                callBackFunction(new IncomingMessage(socket, rawRequestToSend));
            }

        }

        /**
         *  getting the body if its a POST request,then passes the data through event 'data' on req object
         * @param socketData
         * @param data
         * @param req
         */
        function sendBody(socketData, data, req) {
            if (req.method == "POST") {
                console.log('Send Body Function');
                var contentLength = req.headers['content-length'];
                socketData.rawRequest += data;
                //Checks if we the body is shorter then what should be sent, if its, we're sending all the data,
                //And emptying the queue (rawRequest)
                if ((socketData.bodyLengthSent + socketData.rawRequest.length) < contentLength) {
                    req.emit('data', socketData.rawRequest);
                    socketData.bodyLengthSent += socketData.rawRequest.length;
                    socketData.rawRequest = '';
                }

                //If the data sent is bigger from the body, we send only the relevant data
                if ((socketData.bodyLengthSent + socketData.rawRequest.length) >= contentLength) {
                    req.emit('data', socketData.rawRequest.substring(0, (contentLength - socketData.bodyLengthSent)));
                    socketData.rawRequest = socketData.rawRequest.substring((contentLength - socketData.bodyLengthSent), socketData.rawRequest.length);
                    req.emit('end');
                    req.isBodySent = true;
                    socketData.bodyLengthSent = 0;
                }
            }
        }


    });

    server.on('request', function (socketData,req, res,sendBody) {
        handler(req, res);
        sendBody(socketData,req,res);

    });

    util.inherits(server, Server);
    server.prototype.setTimeout=function(msecs,callback){
            server.timeout=msecs;
            server.timeoutCallBack=callback;
     };

    return server;

}


};



 module.exports=miniHttp;
```

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (working and syntactically correct code) so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @remus thanks , I'll add right now.

Answer (score 0):

OK. the issue was that I defined the regex outside the function:

```
var endOfHttpMessageRegexp= /\r\n\r\n/g;
function parseRequest(socket, data, callBackFunction) {
```

So its somehow keeps the last match information (I don't understand preciously how it works).

instead of putting it inside:

```
var endOfHttpMessageRegexp;
function parseRequest(socket, data, callBackFunction) {
     endOfHttpMessageRegexp = /\r\n\r\n/g;
```